# How to create a audioplayer application like pandora app?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, avaudioplayer

I am created an application which play multiple audio files from locally. Audio files are long. Audio player has following options for the user

- Forward,
- Rewind,
- Next Track,
- Previous Track,

I am planning to use AvAudioPlayer so that i can play an audio with long time. When i am changing the audio file ie pressing next track audio. The audioplayer instance is not getting released. This problem is appearing some times only. Please help me..!! I am help less..

Next Track Button IBAction Method

```
- (IBAction) nextTrackPressed
{
    [audioPlay stopAudio];
    if (audioPlay) {
        audioPlay = nil;
        [audioPlay release];
    }

    appDelegate.trackSelected += 1; 
    [self intiNewAudioFile];
    [self play];
}

Initializing audio file through below method

-(void) intiNewAudioFile
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *subPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *filePath = [[NSString alloc] init]; 

    trackObject = [appDelegate.trackDetailArray objectAtIndex:appDelegate.trackSelected];
    NSLog(@"%@",trackObject.trackName);
    // Get the file path to the song to play.
    filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:trackObject.trackName ofType:@"mp3"];

    // Convert the file path to a URL.
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];

    if (audioPlay) {
        audioPlay = nil;
        [audioPlay release];
    }

    audioPlay = [[AudioPlayerClass alloc] init];
    [audioPlay initAudioWithUrl:fileURL];

    [filePath release];
    [fileURL release];
    [subPool release];
}
```

AudioPlayerClass Implementation

```
#import "AudioPlayerClass.h"


@implementation AudioPlayerClass

- (void) initAudioWithUrl: (NSURL *) url
{

    curAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    [curAudioPlayer setDelegate:self];
    [curAudioPlayer prepareToPlay];
}

- (void) playAudio
{
    [curAudioPlayer play];
}

- (void) pauseAudio
{
    [curAudioPlayer pause];
}

- (void) stopAudio
{
    [curAudioPlayer stop];
}

- (BOOL) isAudioPlaying
{
    return curAudioPlayer.playing;
}

- (void) setAudiowithCurrentTime:(NSInteger) time
{
    curAudioPlayer.currentTime = time;
}

- (NSInteger) getAudioFileDuration
{
    return curAudioPlayer.duration;
}

- (NSInteger) getAudioCurrentTime
{
    return curAudioPlayer.currentTime;
}

- (void) releasePlayer
{
    [curAudioPlayer release];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [curAudioPlayer release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Without any code and my cristal ball being in repair this is going to be tough. Please post some relevant code.

Comment: Thanks robin for the reply. I have uploaded the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
if (audioPlay) {
        audioPlay = nil;
        [audioPlay release];
    }
```

You are setting audioPlay to nil before calling release which means that the release message is getting sent to nil. You need to reverse the order of these 2 lines.

```
if (audioPlay) {
        [audioPlay release];
         audioPlay = nil;
    }
```